# When I try to run Minecraft, I receive an error saying it is "Unable to start the Minecraft Runtime Environment"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10

So I got a new computer and went to install Minecraft on it. I finished running the setup wizard, ran the launcher, and hit play once it finished downloading the game from the launcher. Instead of the game launching, this error popped up.

[image: Minecraft error]

I tried to reinstall it by removing all the files and running the launcher setup again. It still said it was corrupted afterward. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you download it here: [https://minecraft.net/](https://minecraft.net/)

Comment: Also; what version of Windows are you running.

Comment: Yes i did download it from that website and i'm running windows 10

Comment: Have you tried either of the solutions I suggested below?

Comment: It works thanks for the help everyone much love <3

Comment: No problem, just make sure to select an answer so others see that the solution works.

Comment: Which solution worked by the way? The alternate launcher or running as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Official Minecraft Forum thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2348169-unable-to-start-the-minecraft-runtime-environment) on this error:

One solution is to:

> Attempt to use the alternative launcher here,
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.exe

-Quote: [cestislife](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2348169-unable-to-start-the-minecraft-runtime-environment?comment=2)

Another is to:

> Try to run the MinecraftLauncher.exe found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\" as Administrator.

-Quote: [DVSProductions](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2348169-unable-to-start-the-minecraft-runtime-environment?comment=3)

The file you're looking for is either:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe*

or:

*C:\Program Files\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe* (On 32-bit versions of Windows; it's probably not since you're running Windows 10)

Find that file then right click on it and left click the option labeled 'Run as administrator'.

Answer (score -1):

For me, this turned out to be an internet access issue. Make sure your firewall or any proxy servers aren't blocking it.